# Complex transmission coefficients for unpolarized light

Tags: optics, polarization, diffraction

My goal is to use a diffraction integral for an optical wave that has traversed a component for which amplitude transmission coefficients for s and p polarized light  are known.

However, I am a bit lost as to how I can express the phase shift sustained by the wave at the exit pupil for unpolarized light.

How may I define it in terms of $t_s$ and $t_p$ ?